# check if exist or remove AlarmManager schedule notification

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

i create number of AlarmManager notification depend on list of times. my list can be change, so user can delete time from list. depend on that i want to delete or to check if exist AlarmManager in the deleted/changed time. 
i read something about to give for every notification an id. but i need to more information about that.

Answer (score 0):

To give you a better answer I would need to see the structure of your code and how you have set up your `AlarmManager`. Below is a simple explanation to set and cancel a scheduled alarm.

```
public void setAlarm(Context context)
{
     AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
     Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
     PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
     alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 10, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
 }

 public void cancelAlarm(Context context)
 {
     Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
     PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
     AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
     alarmManager.cancel(sender);
 }
```

Comment: i a using the code from the sample here:
http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#type